# 2 servers on 2 networks in same office

Tags: networking, windows

My office doesn't have a "server guy" in employ, so I'm stuck with having to fix server issues for now.

There are 2 servers in our office, both are file/web servers only accessible via LAN. They are currently on the same network, so no issue there. Problem is, we recently got a static IP to use, but it's with a different ISP, so now we have 2 routers in our office.

I would like to open one of the servers to the public as a web/FTP server. But if I hook a server up to the new router, users will no longer be able to access the files shared on that server (because they're on different networks).

How can I go about making one server accessible to the public using the static IP line, but still able to share the files on it to the users connected to the other network?

The server I want to make public is running Windows Server 2008, the other server Windows Server 2003. And as far as I know, IP addresses are assigned by the router.

I'm just a developer, don't know much about networking.

Comment: I honestly believe you'll be better off paying a professional to handle this for you. By your own admission this is outside of your field of expertise and by the sounds of it you're looking to get this done as a once-off thing. This may sound condescending, but I'd bet that all the answers below are only going to lead to more questions as you probably have no idea what they mean anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simply - dont change anything on the server. The router will anyway use NAT.... put in a reverse NAT mapping so that requests to specific ports no the public IP address get forwarded to the server. As you dont change anything on the server, it still is reachable from the office.

That would be - port 80 for http, 443 for https if needed, port 20/21 for FTP.

And get someone you can call for config. Really. And learn from him - develoeprs should know the basics of network admin.

And next time - ask on servervault.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a machine to be accessible via both a public and private network the most simple method of setting that up is to install a second network card into the server. That way the machine will be able to communicate with both the private and public networks. Once both network cards are installed you would need to make sure that the server has both a public and private ip address or alternatively is configured to be in the DMZ for the public network or has port forwarding setup for the public network. Then you can configure your web server to serve requests for both the public and private ip addresses. You would also want to make sure that the server has a firewall in place to prevent access to services that should only be accessible via the private network.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dual WAN router like the [Draytek 2955](http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/vigor2955.html), and do port forwarding on that.